# How to delete firebase items that are "expired" or past the current date on Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am creating an Android app that lists local events happening around my campus. Each "event" has children for storing the title, image, category, info, and date. I was wondering what the best way would be to delete events that are past the current date. The date is formatted mm/dd/yy. I don't have much experience with using date functions in Java, and could use some advice.

Here is an [example of an event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZcXy.png). Here is the [source code](https://github.com/aepries/Herds_Social_App/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/aaronpries/herds_social_app) for reference. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to delete them? If you want to filter your data is better to create a Query.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to save your data as a `TIMESTAMP` like this `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
ref.child("yourNode").updateChildren(map);
```

And to get the data back, i suggest you use this method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

To solve your problem, you only need get the date from your database and compare it with the current date and time. If the value of `TIMESTAMP` is less than the current date and time, than you can delete that particular event.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the fire base response on date itself

ex:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("table name");
ref.orderByChild("date").startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate).on("child_added", function(snapshot){
console.log("got the data!", snapshot);
});
```