# update FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with specific values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am working with `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` for my chat module. Now I am looking for some solutions to update my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` based on time value from my firebase database.

I want to show only last 24 hours chats inside `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. User can update this value (24 hours).

I have `"createdAt"` parameter with my every message inside chat. So i based on current time and `"createdAt"` can we filter `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` runtime?

I searched for this, but in every post i did not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you save the date and time as a `TIMESTAMP`, please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621709/how-to-delete-firebase-items-that-are-expired-or-past-the-current-date-on-andr).

The only difference is that you need to comapare with 24h. With your data structure, you can easily build a query that returns only the items that are not older than 30 days and display them. Please use this code:

```
long display = new Date().getTime() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.DAYS);
Query messagesQuery = yourRef.orderByChild("timestamp").endAt(display);
messagesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log("TAG", messageSnapshot.getRef().getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey @Alex thanks for you reply. but i am not having issue with timestamp. But i am unable to hide specific records in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Comment: It's the same principle. You need to compare the data from your database (the value of the `createdAt` field) with the data when you are performing the check. If the the difference is <24h, display the messages else, don't display the messages.

Comment: Ok you mean we will exclude specific records before sending it to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You'll display only the messages which corespond with your condition. What Ibrahim Ali said is incorrect. If you use `limitToLast(3)` method, you don't know if the those 3 messages are within 24h hours or not. In the same way you don't know a starting point and an ending point. That's why you need to verify first and display only those messages which are added no later than 24h.

Comment: @AlexMamo  he may use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` stamp to determine that, i just put example.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. Let me do it. and let you know. Thanks!